# Custom Date Picker in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, time-series, power-bi-report-server

Not all nations use same calendar. Some calendars are lunar (e.g. Hijri) and some are sunar (e.g. Jalali a.k.a. Shamsi).

Looking forward for a tutorial or code sample to create a custom date picker component in Microsoft Power BI Report Server with functions to return original Jalali date or converted Gregorian equivalent.

Thanks.